# I can no longer access mysql as root

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu-16.04

I run Ubuntu 16.04 with MYSQL 5.7.

After I changed the access for the root user in localhost I cannot enter MySQL anymore, searched the internet but did not find a solution.

I am out of options, does anyone have an idea?
It seems strange to remove MySQL altogether and re-install when I see the server running.

What I did

```
mysqld stopped with
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop

startet with
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables

jan@Linux01:~$ sudo mysql -uroot
[sudo] Passwort für jan: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
jan@Linux01:~$ service mysql status
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Don 2018-01-04 22:24:15 CET; 5min ago
  Process: 9021 ExecStartPost=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start post (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 9010 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 9020 (mysqld)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
           └─9020 /usr/sbin/mysqld

Jän 04 22:24:14 Linux01 mysqld[9020]: 2018-01-04T21:24:14.847017Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
Jän 04 22:24:14 Linux01 mysqld[9020]: 2018-01-04T21:24:14.847351Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Jän 04 22:24:14 Linux01 mysqld[9020]: Version: '5.7.20-0ubuntu0.16.04.1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu)
Jän 04 22:24:14 Linux01 mysqld[9020]: 2018-01-04T21:24:14.847384Z 0 [Note] Executing 'SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;' to get a list of tables using the deprecated partition engine. You may use the startup option '-
Jän 04 22:24:14 Linux01 mysqld[9020]: 2018-01-04T21:24:14.847388Z 0 [Note] Beginning of list of non-natively partitioned tables
Jän 04 22:24:14 Linux01 mysqld[9020]: 2018-01-04T21:24:14.904105Z 0 [Note] End of list of non-natively partitioned tables
Jän 04 22:24:15 Linux01 mysqld[9020]: 2018-01-04T21:24:15.429487Z 3 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
Jän 04 22:24:15 Linux01 systemd[1]: Started MySQL Community Server.
```

Comment: Have you tried mysql -uroot, without the sudo?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Database Administrators Stack Exchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see that stopping `mysql` that way is the real problem, but there's a typo when entering mysql `mysql -uroot` is altogether, when is `mysql -u root -p`, plus your password.

I'm also a Ubuntu 16.04 with mysql 5.7 as you can see:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

returns this

> mysql -u root -p
>   Enter password:
>   Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
>   Your MySQL connection id is 21
>   Server version: 5.7.20-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (Ubuntu)
>
> Copyright (c) 2000, 2017, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
>
> Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
>   affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
>   owners.
>
> Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.
>
> mysql>

**EDITED TO ADD UP**

If you try it like

```
mysql -uroot
```

Yes, you get that ERROR 1045(28000): Access denied ...

Comment: It's important to use the -p flag if there is a password on the root account (there is).

Comment: Hi,I tried with and without spaces, I know Mysql. In 5.7.2 there ar these "plugins" and I assume that is the problem. I am afraid that only a complete de-install and a new install wil bring me mysql back, I have backups of all dbs so that will not be a problem.